# Hibernate replication issues - does the session really need to be replicated?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, ehcache

I have discovered a strange case when trying to replicate a Hibernate 2nd level cache key upon object update.

The cache key structure is like this:

```
cacheKey = {org.hibernate.cache.CacheKey}
|- key = {my.own.serializable.class}
|- type = {org.hibernate.type.ComponentType}
| |- typeScope = {org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory$TypeScopeImpl}
| | |- factory = {org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl}
| |- propertyNames = {...}
| |- propertyTypes = {...}
| |- propertyNullability = {...}
| |- propertySpan = 2
| |- cascade = {...}
| |- joinedFetch = {...}
| |- isKey = true
| |- tuplizerMapping = {...}
|- entityOrRoleName = {java.lang.String} "my.Entity"
|- entityMode = {org.hibernate.EntityMode}
|- hashCode = 588688
```

The problem I can see here is that `cacheKey.type.typeScope` has a reference to the local `o.h.i.SessionFactoryImpl` which gets replicated over. Should `typeScope` (or one of its ancestors) not be declared as transient?

Looking at the `o.h.t.ComponentType` class I can see that `typeScope` attribute is not used at all in this class but only set in the constructor and kept in. Is this a Hibernate bug?

NOTE: `o.h.t.ComponentType` is used when the entity has a composite key and uses special identifier object for it.

We use Hibernate v3.6.7 and Ehcache v2.4.4. This has also been posted on the [Hibernate Users forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1013687).

EDIT:
I opened [HHH-6880](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6880), without much success so far.

I have also posted a similar message to the [Ehcache users mailing list](http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/0/6378.page) and Alex@Terracotta suggested this was a genuine issue, likely introduced by HHH-5182 in version 3.6 and also affecting things like Ehcache serialization to disk. Here's a link to [hibernate-dev thread](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-dev/2011-December/007431.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Hibernate team feels this has been resolved in 4.0.1, by fixing [HHH-6822](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6822).